# Databases for perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

So I have been trying to find a database that offers perfect numbers. I need this to help me and a friend with a project that we have been working on for a while involving the odd perfect number conjecture and I haven't had any luck finding any such database. If anybody knows of such a database or could suggest how to get hold of a wide array of perfect numbers that I could then use for analysis, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links to help you out with finding data:-

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers
2. https://oeis.org/A000396/graph
3. https://oeis.org/A000396/list
4. http://web.mit.edu/adorai/www/perfectnumbers.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a few, http://web.mit.edu/adorai/www/perfectnumbers.html  and http://www.mersenne.org/primes/ has a note on the sides about perfects

Answer (score 3):

The even perfect numbers are specific multiples of Mersenne primes: if $2^p - 1$ is prime, then $(2^{p - 1})(2^p - 1)$ is a perfect number.

So if you can't find a database of perfect numbers, the next best thing is a database of Mersenne primes, such as this one: http://www.mersenne.org/primes/ (notice that it has a column for perfect numbers).

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to include numbers with abundancy index
$$I(x) = \dfrac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
equal to an integer which is at least $3$, then you can check out [The Multiply Perfect Numbers Page](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html), last updated by Achim Flammenkamp on 2014-01-25 19:35 UTC+1.